# large outdoor/city maps

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am looking for large outdoor environments, possibly (but not necessarily) representing a portion of a city, or some buildings. Is it possible to import such a scenario? If yes, where can I find it? Thank you in advance :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4938/large-outdoor/city-maps/) by [kr1zz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/390/kr1zz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We created a few large outdoor environments for the virtual robotics challenge. The world live in the [drcsim](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim) package.

Here is [one example world](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/797063ded38aa666916c3b02dfec57f9fa7d5699/drcsim_model_resources/worlds/vrc_final_task1.world?at=default).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/390/kr1zz/) on 2013-11-07**:
Thank you Nate, that looks appropriate :)